# 301 redirects .htaccess fix

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I wanted to do 301 redirects from HTTP to HTTPS version of my website. So I put following content into .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off          [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.   [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://domain.tld/%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

The problem is that sometimes the redirect on my homepage works in such a way, that i end up with `https://domain.tld//` (2 slashes at the end). Is there any way to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off          [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.   [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://domain.tld%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Without slash.
Because `%{REQUEST_URI}` always starts with a `/`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it and now it redirects me to https://domain.tld with no slash at the end. I don't know if that's a problem, but all other urls seem to have a single slash at the end

Comment: Clear your cache, or try with other browser. With some browsers, even by adding a / in the url it is deleted to the display. In all cases the link is the same. In a html link it should be added, no one does it to visit the site.